# How to execute logic on Optional if not present?

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I want to replace the following code using java8 `Optional`:

```
public Obj getObjectFromDB() {
    Obj obj = dao.find();
    if (obj != null) {
        obj.setAvailable(true);
    } else {
        logger.fatal("Object not available");
    }

    return obj;
}
```

The following pseudocode does not work as there is no `orElseRun` method, but anyways it illustrates my purpose:

```
public Optional<Obj> getObjectFromDB() {
    Optional<Obj> obj = dao.find();
    return obj.ifPresent(obj.setAvailable(true)).orElseRun(logger.fatal("Object not available"));
}
```

Comment: What are you wanting to return from the method if there isn't an object present?

Comment: I'd want to return `Optional` always as indicated by the method return parameter.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

With Java 9 or higher, [`ifPresentOrElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresentOrElse-java.util.function.Consumer-java.lang.Runnable-) is most likely what you want:

```java
Optional<> opt = dao.find();

opt.ifPresentOrElse(obj -> obj.setAvailable(true),
                    () -> logger.error("…"));
```

Currying using [vavr](http://www.vavr.io/) or alike might get even neater code, but I haven't tried yet.

Comment: seems like something that should have been included in v1 (Java 8)... _oh well..._

Comment: Yes... I also think they actually missed that in Java 8. And more... if you want to do something when the value is present, they gave "ifPresent()". If you want to do something when the value is present and other thing when it's not, they gave "ifPresentOrElse(f1, f2)". But it still lacks if I only want to do something with it's not present (something like "ifNotPresent()" would be suitable). With ifPresentOrElse I'm forced to use a present function that does nothing in the later case.

Comment: If you can introduce a framework, have a look at Vavr (former Javaslang) and their Option, it has an [onEmpty method](https://static.javadoc.io/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.0/io/vavr/control/Option.html#onEmpty-java.lang.Runnable-)

Comment: Rather use Java 9 or use if, else. vavr is not very nice

Comment: this is excessively complex just for a straight if then else!

Comment: Of course there should be an `ifNotPresent(() -> { ... })` option. Yet another case where Java's APIs get 70% there and then quit, leaving the developer wanting more. :( There are legit use cases where you don't want to do _anything_ if the optional exists, and only care if it does _not_ exist. Using `ifPresentOrElse` feels slimy for this use case.

Comment: imo there should be a `ifAbsent`. I always run into instances where that would be useful.

Comment: Just to add for people browsing this, sometimes you just need to throw your custom Exception. If that's the case, you could do it like this: `.orElseThrow(() -> new MyException("There is nothing to see here. Move along"))`.

Answer (score 44):

I don't think you can do it in a single statement. Better do:

```
if (!obj.isPresent()) {
    logger.fatal(...);   
} else {
    obj.get().setAvailable(true);
}
return obj;
```

Comment: This may be the right answer, but in what way is this superior to `null` checks? From my point of view it is worse without an `orElse...`.

Comment: @DaRich, you can forget about the null in the middle of your code, what results in the NPE. But you can't ignore an `Optional` by accident, it's always an explicit (and dangerous) decision.

Answer (score 25):

For Java 8 Spring Data offers [`ifPresentOrElse`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/2.1.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/util/Optionals.html#ifPresentOrElse-java.util.Optional-java.util.function.Consumer-java.lang.Runnable-) from "Utility methods to work with Optionals" to achieve what you want.
Example would be:

```java
import static org.springframework.data.util.Optionals.ifPresentOrElse;    
    
ifPresentOrElse(dao.find(), obj -> obj.setAvailable(true), () -> logger.fatal("Object not available"));
```

Comment: Useful things always hide deep, until magician have nice mood.

Answer (score 11):

You will have to split this into multiple statements. Here is one way to do that:

```
if (!obj.isPresent()) {
  logger.fatal("Object not available");
}

obj.ifPresent(o -> o.setAvailable(true));
return obj;
```

Another way (possibly over-engineered) is to use `map`:

```
if (!obj.isPresent()) {
  logger.fatal("Object not available");
}

return obj.map(o -> {o.setAvailable(true); return o;});
```

If `obj.setAvailable` conveniently returns `obj`, then you can simply the second example to:

```
if (!obj.isPresent()) {
  logger.fatal("Object not available");
}

return obj.map(o -> o.setAvailable(true));
```

Answer (score 11):

There **is** an `.orElseRun` method, but it is called `.orElseGet`.

The main problem with your pseudocode is that `.isPresent` doesn't return an `Optional<>`. But `.map` returns an `Optional<>` which has the `orElseGet` method.

If you really want to do this in one statement this is possible:

```
public Optional<Obj> getObjectFromDB() {
    return dao.find()
        .map( obj -> { 
            obj.setAvailable(true);
            return Optional.of(obj); 
         })
        .orElseGet( () -> {
            logger.fatal("Object not available"); 
            return Optional.empty();
    });
}
```

But this is even clunkier than what you had before.

Answer (score 9):

First of all, your `dao.find()` should either return an `Optional<Obj>` or you will have to create one.

e.g.

```
Optional<Obj> = dao.find();
```

or you can do it yourself like:

```
Optional<Obj> = Optional.ofNullable(dao.find());
```

this one will return `Optional<Obj>` if present or `Optional.empty()` if not present.

So now let's get to the solution,

```
public Obj getObjectFromDB() {
   return Optional.ofNullable(dao.find()).flatMap(ob -> {
            ob.setAvailable(true);
            return Optional.of(ob);    
        }).orElseGet(() -> {
            logger.fatal("Object not available");
            return null;
        });
    }
```

This is the one liner you're looking for :)

Comment: Returning a null defeats the purpose of Optionals. In the OPs question, what one must do if the object is not found is ambiguous. IMHO its better to return a newly instantiated Object, and perhaps setAvailable to false. 
Of course, here the OP has logged fatal, which means he probably intends to terminate so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: This solution returns an `Object`, while the original question is for a method returning `Optional<Object>`. My (older) answer is very similar but differs in this way : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36681079/3854962

Comment: Why the use of `flatMap`?

Comment: because he's returning an optional instead of a value. FlatMap converts Optional<Optional<X>> to Optional<X>

Answer (score 5):

For those of you who want to execute a side-effect **only if an optional is absent**

i.e. an equivalent of `ifAbsent()` or `ifNotPresent()` here is a slight modification to the great answers already provided.

```
myOptional.ifPresentOrElse(x -> {}, () -> {
  // logic goes here
})
```

Comment: ifPresentOrElse requires Java 9.

Answer (score 5):

#### Title: "How to execute logic on Optional if not present?"

#### Answer:

Use `orElseGet()` as a workaround for the missing `ifNotPresent()`. And since it expects us to return something just return
`null`.

```java
Optional.empty().orElseGet(() -> {
    System.out.println("The object is not present");
    return null;
});

//output: The object is not present
```

or

```java
Optional.ofNullable(null).orElseGet(() -> {
    System.out.println("The object is not present");
    return null;
});

//output: The object is not present
```

I also use it to easily implement the [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) with lazy initialization.

```java
public class Settings {
    private Settings(){}    
    private static Settings instance;
    public static synchronized Settings getInstance(){
        Optional.ofNullable(instance).orElseGet(() -> instance = new Settings());
        return instance;
    } 
}
```

Of course the `getInstance()` content can be written in one line by directly returning the first statement, but I wanted to demonstrate the use of `orElseGet()` as an `ifNotPresent()`.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to came up with a couple of "one line" solutions, for example:

```
    obj.map(o -> (Runnable) () -> o.setAvailable(true))
       .orElse(() -> logger.fatal("Object not available"))
       .run();
```

or

```
    obj.map(o -> (Consumer<Object>) c -> o.setAvailable(true))
       .orElse(o -> logger.fatal("Object not available"))
       .accept(null);
```

or

```
    obj.map(o -> (Supplier<Object>) () -> {
            o.setAvailable(true);
            return null;
    }).orElse(() () -> {
            logger.fatal("Object not available")
            return null;
    }).get();
```

It doesn't look very nice, something like `orElseRun` would be much better, but I think that option with Runnable is acceptable if you really want one line solution.

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8 `Optional` it can be done with:

```
    Optional<Obj> obj = dao.find();

    obj.map(obj.setAvailable(true)).orElseGet(() -> {
        logger.fatal("Object not available");
        return null;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the value from one call, or do an extra call if the previous returned an empty value, you can chain the commands.

```
public Optional<Obj> getObjectFromDB() {
    return dao.find().or(() -> dao.findBySomethingElse());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [Optional.isPresent()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#isPresent--) and [orElse()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-). Your snippet won;t work because it doesn't return anything if not present.

The point of Optional is to return it from the method.

Answer (score 0):

**ifPresentOrElse** can handle cases of nullpointers as well. Easy approach.

```
   Optional.ofNullable(null)
            .ifPresentOrElse(name -> System.out.println("my name is "+ name),
                    ()->System.out.println("no name or was a null pointer"));
```

Answer (score -2):

I suppose you cannot change the `dao.find()` method to return an instance of `Optional<Obj>`, so you have to create the appropriate one yourself.

The following code should help you out. I've create the class `OptionalAction`,
which provides the if-else mechanism for you.

```
public class OptionalTest
{
  public static Optional<DbObject> getObjectFromDb()
  {
    // doa.find()
    DbObject v = find();

    // create appropriate Optional
    Optional<DbObject> object = Optional.ofNullable(v);

    // @formatter:off
    OptionalAction.
    ifPresent(object)
    .then(o -> o.setAvailable(true))
    .elseDo(o -> System.out.println("Fatal! Object not available!"));
    // @formatter:on
    return object;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Optional<DbObject> object = getObjectFromDb();
    if (object.isPresent())
      System.out.println(object.get());
    else
      System.out.println("There is no object!");
  }

  // find may return null
  public static DbObject find()
  {
    return (Math.random() > 0.5) ? null : new DbObject();
  }

  static class DbObject
  {
    private boolean available = false;

    public boolean isAvailable()
    {
      return available;
    }

    public void setAvailable(boolean available)
    {
      this.available = available;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
      return "DbObject [available=" + available + "]";
    }
  }

  static class OptionalAction
  {
    public static <T> IfAction<T> ifPresent(Optional<T> optional)
    {
      return new IfAction<>(optional);
    }

    private static class IfAction<T>
    {
      private final Optional<T> optional;

      public IfAction(Optional<T> optional)
      {
        this.optional = optional;
      }

      public ElseAction<T> then(Consumer<? super T> consumer)
      {
        if (optional.isPresent())
          consumer.accept(optional.get());
        return new ElseAction<>(optional);
      }
    }

    private static class ElseAction<T>
    {
      private final Optional<T> optional;

      public ElseAction(Optional<T> optional)
      {
        this.optional = optional;
      }

      public void elseDo(Consumer<? super T> consumer)
      {
        if (!optional.isPresent())
          consumer.accept(null);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please leave a comment, if you vote down. This helps me to improve the answer.

Comment: I agree downvoter should comment here. I assume this is because I was looking to refactor java7 to java8 code, whereas the old code consisted of 8 lines. And if I *would* replace it with your suggestion that would not help anybody, but just make things worse.

Comment: I don't understand your point. I did refactor java 7 to 8, didn't I? And to what extend would it make things worse? I don't see any flaws in this solution. One could argue whether the whole point of having an else (or a workaround) on `Optional` makes sense. But I correctly answered your question and provided a working example.

Comment: Your solution seems totally valid to me, mike. Anyways introducing explicit classes like `OptionalAction` as a workaround for being able to port the code to java8 seems a bit overengineered, if in java7 this is already only a few liner.

Comment: You **must have** all the `*Action` classes, there is no other way to get the method chaining as you purposed in your question. Of course they are problem agnostic utilitliy classes and reusable. The `DbObject` was just introduced for the sake of a running example.

Comment: Optional<DbObject> object = (v == null) ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(v);

may be rewritten to:

    Optional<DbObject> object = Optional.ofNullable(v);