# Do void actions on an Optional, Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, option-type

I have some handling logic:

```
public void handle(String uniqueId) {
    Optional<Config> config = configDAO.find(uniqueId);
    if (!config.isPresent()) {
        LOGGER.warn("config not found for uniqueId '{}'", uniqueId);
    } else {
        internalHandle(config.get());
    }
}
```

In other words, I want to run one of two void operations, based of existance of the Optional value.

I have strong concern of not using `isPresent` in my code, but it looks like java8 doesn't provide anything I could replace this code with.

Comment: why wouldn't you want to use it?

Comment: You are correct that `isPresent` is low-level and that usually better options exist. Can you use Java 9? It’s got `ifPresentOrElse`, which fits your need very nicely.

Comment: this is why I tagged question as `java-8`

Comment: @DenisKurochkin check this may be could useful:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29235982/how-to-execute-logic-on-optional-if-not-present/39958306#answer-53840137

Comment: There is nothing about your code, it is the java 8 intended way

Comment: when `Config` not exist can use some `String` represent you can try use `orElseGet`

Answer (score 1):

As it was mentioned in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54866780/do-void-actions-on-an-optional/54866891#comment96503965_54866780) in java9 you can use [`ifPresentOrElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresentOrElse-java.util.function.Consumer-java.lang.Runnable-)  :

```
config.ifPresentOrElse(c -> internalHandle(c), 
           () -> LOGGER.warn("config not found for uniqueId '{}'", uniqueId));
```

Implementation of `ifPresentOrElse` if pretty simple using `if else` statement. From source code:

```
public void ifPresentOrElse(Consumer<? super T> action, Runnable emptyAction) {
    if (value != null) {
        action.accept(value);
    } else {
        emptyAction.run();
    }
}
```

So I guess it is appropriate to use `if else` logic as in your example in case of java 8.

Comment: this is why I tagged question as `java-8`

Comment: @DenisKurochkin Well it's obviously not possible in Java 8, otherwise they wouldn't have added the method in Java 9...

Comment: While this answer doesn’t help the asker, who is currently using Java 8, it will certainly help other readers.